# Call app within another app and get a response from this app

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I am developing an application for this new card machines that look like a smartphone, but inside my app I should call the card machine payment app and get a payment answer if it worked or not, 
Would there be any way to do this to get the application response that was opened by my application?

I tried using Linking, but every time you open the app, it returns true, that is, it returns true because the app was opened, not the response that the app returns would be if the payment went well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAmkS.png)

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: I added a diagram about the process

Comment: I guess you need to use other way to communicate with the payment app. The Linking API only redirects you to the app and will not retrieve a callback. You can try some packages like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-activity-result

Comment: thx, 
I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the personal help but I did it, develop a module in react-native to call the application and get feedback by deepLinks thanks everyone follow her link

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-deep-link-with-response